# How do I delete wine-staging-i?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, wine, uninstall

I am trying to remove wine and all of its remnants. When I use    `dpkg-query -l '*wine*'`    it tells me I have rc wine-staging-i version 1.9.10 with i386 architecture installed, but when I try to remove it outputs    `E: Unable to locate package wine-staging-i`    . I am running ubuntu 14.04 on a samsung chromebook with an intel processor. I'm sure it's obvious, but I'm super new to all of this and have no idea what I'm doing. I just trial and error-ed myself to this point. I apologize for any formatting or phrasing errors.

Comment: As a new user, you might want to use a package manager with a graphical interface, such as Synaptic (or even Aptitude in a console), rather than the command-line utilities. Other people may have a more direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type in `sudo apt-get remove wine` and let it uninstall wine. If there is a package in your machine that is truly installed called `wine-staging-i` simply type in `sudo apt-get remove wine-staging-i` and it will remove that package.

If it claims that `wine-staging-i` is not apparent on your machine... it means it isn't.

You can also use Systemback - A free program for Ubuntu 14.04 that allows you to backup your files, and even restore your system.

Try restoring your system to a point it was before you installed Wine.

Also, type in `sudo apt-get remove playonlinux` - A lot of users install PlayOnLinux carelessly alongside Wine, so please remove that as well (Optional).

Comment: I have tried a variety of combinations of apt-get purge/remove combined with everything from 'wine-staging-i' to 'wine...' and it tells me it can't locate it. For other programs like playonlinux, it outputs 0 upgraded, installed,removed, etc. I just want to be sure it's gone because I have to reinstall wine, and I don't want them to interfere with each other.

Comment: Reinstalling wine will not interfere with anything. Just simply do `sudo apt-get install wine` and it will reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. 
1st, Please note that "WINE" is a completely different program from "Wine Staging."   In fact they each have their own versions  & updates. 
With that in mind, 1st check to see *exactly* what WINE you have installed.
[from terminal] 
WINE --version 
In my case I had:
wine-2.21 (Staging)

To REMOVE it: 
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine-staging

General rule of thumb:
If you see elsewhere (as I've seen) instructions on removing "WINE" or other Linux programs, ju substitute "WINE" or "WINE-staging" depending upon exactly what you have.